# Python re module's cache clearing

Tags: python, regex, caching

While reading the documentation on Python `re` module I decided to have a look on `re.py` source code.

When I opened it, I found this:

```
_cache = {}
_MAXCACHE = 100

def _compile(*key):
    cachekey = (type(key[0]),) + key
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
    if p is not None:
        return p

    #...Here I skip some part of irrelevant to the question code...

    if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
        _cache.clear()
    _cache[cachekey] = p
    return p
```

Why is the cache cleared using`_cache.clear()` when it reaches `_MAXCACHE` of entries?

Is it common approach to clear cache completely and start from scratch?

Why just not used the longest time ago cashed value is deleted?

Comment: Interesting question. I suppose it could have been laziness on the part of the developer who wrote this code, or perhaps "Simple is better than complex" thinking. :-)

Comment: I thought there may be some scientific research which justifies such approach of clearing cache on its reaching some constant value in size.

Comment: It might be interesting to look at the source of the new regex module under development tracked here: http://bugs.python.org/issue2636.  The description includes the term "Smart Caching" so there may be some improvements made in that area.

Comment: @F.J So, the comment about "laziness on the part of the developer" is not groundless :)

Comment: @ovgolovin - Not at all, in fact I just posted another answer that pretty much contradicts my first one completely, with a quote from the developer of the new regex module :) Leaving my first answer up as a "what the original developer might have been thinking".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess I'd say that it was done this way to avoid having to keep track of when / how long individual values had been stored in the cache, which would create both memory and processing overhead.  Because the caching object being used is a dictionary, which is inherently unordered, there's no good way to know what order items were added to it without some other caching object as well.  This could be addressed by using an OrderedDict in place of a standard dictionary, assuming you're working with Python >= 2.7, but otherwise, you'd need to significantly redesign the way the caching was implemented in order to eliminate the need for a `clear()`.

Comment: Is it difficult to implement `cache` using `OrderedDict`? To my mind, using order of the elements makes it possible to arrange them in order of last usage. And reusing of a compiled object would just require to move the cached value to the beginning of `OrderedDict` by popping it and placing in the dictionary again.

Comment: @ovgolovin - You could pop / re-add the value to move it back to the bottom of the list, is possible.  I wouldn't consider it difficult, no.

Comment: I thought there may be some scientific research which justifies such approach of clearing cache on its reaching some constant value in size.

Comment: If you use an OrderedDict for the cache you would lose the O(1) lookup performance, the whole point of the cache is to improve performance so that would not be an acceptable trade-off

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quote from one of the developers of a new `regex` module scheduled for 3.3 regarding the caching, this is part of a list of features that separates the new module from the current `re` module.

> 7) Modify the re compiled expression cache to better handle the
>   thrashing condition.  Currently, when regular expressions are compiled,
>   the result is cached so that if the same expression is compiled again,
>   it is retrieved from the cache and no extra work has to be done.  This
>   cache supports up to 100 entries.  Once the 100th entry is reached, the
>   cache is cleared and a new compile must occur.  The danger, all be it
>   rare, is that one may compile the 100th expression only to find that one
>   recompiles it and has to do the same work all over again when it may
>   have been done 3 expressions ago.  By modifying this logic slightly, it
>   is possible to establish an arbitrary counter that gives a time stamp to
>   each compiled entry and instead of clearing the entire cache when it
>   reaches capacity, only eliminate the oldest half of the cache, keeping
>   the half that is more recent.  This should limit the possibility of
>   thrashing to cases where a very large number of Regular Expressions are
>   continually recompiled.  In addition to this, I will update the limit to
>   256 entries, meaning that the 128 most recent are kept.

http://bugs.python.org/issue2636

This seems to indicate that it is more likely the laziness of the developer or "an emphasis on readability" that explains the current caching behavior.

Comment: I have opened `regex` module's source code (I've been using it for about a fortnight). The block of code that is responsible for clearing cache is the following `if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:  shrink_cache(_cache, _named_args, _MAXCACHE)`. But I haven't found any `shrink_cache` function on the module. There is no such function.

Comment: Still, the author sticks with eliminating big chunks of cache, not single element when it's needed. The new approach eliminates the least recent half of the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The point of caching is to decrease the average call time of the function.  The overhead associated with keeping more information in `_cache` and pruning it instead of clearing it would increase that average call time.  The `_cache.clear()` call will complete quickly, and even though you lose your cache this is preferable to maintaining a cache state and having the overhead of removing individual elements from the cache when the limit is reached.

There are a few things to think about when calculating the cache efficiency:

1. Average call time on cache hits (very short)
2. Average call time on cache misses (longer)
3. Frequency of cache hits (fairly uncommon)
4. Call time when cache is cleared or pruned (fairly uncommon)

The question is does increasing #3 make sense if it means increasing #2 and #4 as well.  My guess is that it doesn't, or the difference is negligible enough that keeping the code simple is preferable.

Comment: But the overhead associated with keeping more information in `_cache` will be predictable. But clearing `_cache` in sporadic moments will make assessing of cache efficiency very bothersome, since it will be very dependable on the moments when `cache` is cleared.